# Camera position defined in URDF vs broadcast a TF

Tags: rviz, transform, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a depth camera mounted on a robot and I define its position in the URDF. It works fine in RVIZ. But when RVIZ is not running, I am wondering if the system still knows depth camera position or not. Do I need to broadcast a TF to show the camera position? If yes, will it conflict with the URDF when RVIZ is running? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316389/camera-position-defined-in-urdf-vs-broadcast-a-tf/) by [ytosclee](https://answers.ros.org/users/36977/ytosclee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2019-02-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

["robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) uses the URDF specified by the parameter robot_description and the joint positions from the topic joint_states to calculate the forward kinematics of the robot and publish the results via tf."

Essentially, if you can already see the robot model in RVIZ, your robot_description parameter should be set to the correct URDF. So all you need to do is launch the robot_state_publisher. In ROS tutorials, this scenario is explained [here](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher).

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2019-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1